# Add interval between variables in sprintf

Tags: php, intervals

I've got this code snippet:

```
$format = '%s' . $format;
return sprintf($format, number_format((double)$amount, $decimal, $decimal_point, $thousand_sep), $currency);
```

I would like to add an interval/blank space that would show up between number_format and $currency. Can you tell me how this could be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: What is the initial value of $format?

Comment: You can specify that in the variable `$format`. For example: `$format = "%s %s";`. Notice the space between the two `%s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you want to format your string like this:

```
$format = '%s %s';
return sprintf($format, number_format((double)$amount, $decimal, $decimal_point, $thousand_sep), $currency);
```

PS: I don't know where the `$format = '%s' . $format;` came from, as you haven't specified what value $format was assigned to before that statement. 
Also, it can't hurt to read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

EDIT: 
if the number_format() function returns a double change `$format = '%s %s';` to `$format = '%g %s';`